# Custom url handler returning 404 when still being handled by correct action

Tags: php, routes, silverstripe

I've got an action `details` that is handling the URLs:

```
something/details/Location/6
```

and this works fine. However I want to put extra detail on the end, basically for SEO.

I have in my routes.yml:

```
---
Name: mysiteroutes
---
Director:
  rules:
    'something//$Action/$Location/$OtherID': 'SomeController'
```

and in my controller:

```
private static $url_handlers = array(
    'something//$Action/$Location/$OtherID' => 'handleAction'
);
```

If I go to the URL above it works, however if I go to `something/details/Location/6/test` it returns a 404, even though the action is still being loaded and returning itself with a `renderWith()`

How can I get this to work? I don't care about the details after the ID either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can add more a Parameter at last

```
---
Name: mysiteroutes
---
Director:
  rules:
    'something': 'SomeController'
```

and your controller

```
private static $allowed_actions = array('details');
private static $url_handlers = array(
    'details/$Location/$OtherID/$otherParam' => 'details'
);
public function details() {
    $this->getRequest()->param('otherParam');
    /* more processing goes here */
}
```

More infomation
https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/controllers/routing/

Comment: I did try this but no dice. I am using SS 3 as well.

Comment: Because your pattern has more than 2 parameters. I try edit my answer. You can try this

Comment: This seems dodgy but it works. Not that I need it scalable atm but if you wanted the action "furtherdetail" would just adding it in the url handler be enough?